# Is there any way to constrain a type parameter to EITHER a reference type OR a nullable value type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints, nullable

It'd be nice if I could define a method like this:

```
public T GetItem<T>() where T : null
{
    if (someCondition<T>())
        return someCalculation<T>();
    else
        return null;
}
```

Then I could use this on reference types (e.g., `object`, `string`) **as well as** nullable value types (e.g., `int?`, `double?`): anything that can be assigned to `null`. But this isn't possible.

Then again, for all I know, maybe it is? I know there'a no `null` constraint like I just fantasized about; but is there some workaround or clever way of accomplishing this that just hasn't occurred to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to never use output parameters, partly I think the syntax just felt clumsy.  However, a few years ago I started using them more and they've become a common aspect of the code that I write.

I think this is the kind of function where I would really consider writing the function with an output parameter and a boolean return type, as shown below:

```
public bool GetItem<T>(out T value)
{
    if (someCondition<T>())
    {
        value = someCalculation<T>();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this approach there is no need to restrict your generic parameter to reference type or a nullable type.

As I mentioned above, I originally felt that output parameter syntax was clumsy, but after I really started using it frequently I felt that the code that consumed my functions with output parameters was actually more accurate towards representing the problem that I was trying to solve, if that makes any sense.

Comment: I do this quite a bit myself as well. I suppose this is a fairly close alternative that captures the spirit of what I'm asking about, so +1.

Comment: Since it seems this ends up being the most sensible pattern for this problem (in *my* opinion, anyway -- I know there are a lot of `out` parameter naysayers out there), I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would create two overloaded generic methods: one that accepts reference types and another that accepts nullable value types. Then you'll be able to call with either kind of  parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I do this quite a bit as well. But this requires giving the methods different names, which is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the generic usage in the `someCondition` and `someCalculation` methods. But  this sounds like where the 'default' keyword could be used.

```
return default(T);
```

Comment: Well, I'm concerned with scenarios where I would want to be able to distinguish success from failure on the basis of the return value being `null` or not. With `int`, for example, `default(int)` is just `0`, which could be a valid return value for a huge variety of functions.

Comment: @Dan, that situation makes sense. I would probably follow the TryParse pattern --even though I despise output variables. I assumed you were well aware of the 'default' so my answer was pretty silly.